# Directory symlink creation on windows server

Tags: operating-system, filesystems

I have one windows server 2019 on which command `mklink /D` seems to work from command prompt (no error, directory created) but does not create the link directory.
Both linked directory and link itself are on the same folder, hence located in the same drive.

`mklink /J` works on another hand.

What could be the reason for such a behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

it seems you use the `mklink /D` cmd and it doesn't work, it could be related to the permissions or the file system used on the Windows Server 2019.
Please ensure that the file system used on the drive is **NTFS** and not **FAT32** 
and try to run your command prompt **as Administrator** and try this cmd :

```
mklink /D "C:\Path\To\LinkDirectory" "C:\Path\To\LinkedDirectory"
```

replace `"C:\Path\To\LinkDirectory"` and `"C:\Path\To\LinkedDirectory"` with the actual paths on your system

Comment: Thanks I will check as soon as I'm connected to the customer's VM what is the file system. Command prompt was launched as administrator, paths were quoted.

Comment: Nice try, but the file system is NTFS

Comment: okay make sure there is no file or directory with the same name as the symbolic link you are trying to create and re-run the `cmd`

Comment: No as I said the command is successful but the link is not created :D. There is no directory with the same name.